# redirect domain to include local in url via apache or rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, seo, apache2

I have many sites that run on a hosted rails 3 application on apache.

They can be multi-lingual and the domains are in this format www.example1.com/en  ,  www.example2.com/de/pages/about-us  , example3.hosted_sites.com/it/products/cars/hondas

The problem is that each domain has a www.example1.com domain as well that just uses the english local.     This means that there is duplicate content on the 2 version ed www.example1.com and www.example1.com/en   etc

What is the best way to add the /en into the requested url if a local is not specified ?

does anyone know a apache rule to do this ?   i have many sites so its got to be generic / dynamic as cant look for a certain url in the url.

Or is this best done in my rails 3 app via a before filter ?  anyone know how ?

Thanks alot
Rick

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar scenario and use [this](https://github.com/raul/translate_routes) plugin. It handles your translated routes with one default, eg

```
domain/someid --> english
domain/es/someid --> spanish
domain/de/someid --> german
```

https://github.com/raul/translate_routes